# Ionic 3 alert popup

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am having a strange problem, when an alert appears and i dismiss it with the "ok" button and calling it again makes the alert appear twice now.
Cant figure it out what is going on, how i know at dismiss the alert is destroyed but its not.

The code is like in the ionicframework documentation:

```
presentAlert() {
  const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Low battery',
    subTitle: '10% of battery remaining',
    buttons: ['Dismiss']
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

Lets say the function in bound to a click function on a button. Clicking on it makes it appear. Then closing it with the dismiss button and then clicking the open button again will make it appear two times.
Thanks in advance,
Trix

Added full code:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import leaflet from 'leaflet';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-map',
  templateUrl: 'map.html',
})
export class MapPage {

  view: string = "map";
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
  @ViewChild('map') mapContainer: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  locations: any;
  private markerGroupSelf: any;
  public alert: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    this.locations = [
      ["Popup1",true,46.0331797,17.9968659],
      ["Popup2",true,46.0331797,17.8968659],
      ["Popup3",true,46.0331797,17.7968659],
      ["Popup4",true,46.0331797,17.6968659],
      ["Popup5",true,46.0331797,17.5968659],
      ["Popup6",true,46.0331797,17.4968659],
      ["Popup7",true,46.0331797,17.3968659],
      ["Popup8",false,46.0331797,17.2968659],
      ["Popup9",true,46.0331797,17.1968659]
    ];
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.getMap();
  }

  presentAlert() {
    this.alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'GPS error',
      subTitle: 'Please turn on your gps!',
      buttons: ['Dismiss']
      });
      this.alert.present();
  }

  getMap() {
    this.map = leaflet.map("map");
    leaflet.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attributions: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
      minZoom: 6
    }).addTo(this.map); 

    this.map.bounds = [],

    this.map.fitBounds([
      [45.636684, 16.030223],
      [48.708459, 22.863228]
    ]);

    this.map.setMaxBounds([
      [45.636684, 16.030223],
      [48.708459, 22.863228]
    ]);

    let markerGroup = leaflet.featureGroup();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.locations.length; i++) {
      if(this.locations[i][1] == true){
        let location: any = leaflet.marker([this.locations[i][2],this.locations[i][3]]).bindPopup('<strong>'+ this.locations[i][0] +'</strong>')
        .openPopup();
        markerGroup.addLayer(location);
      }

      let radius: any = leaflet.circle([this.locations[i][2],this.locations[i][3]], 5000).addTo(this.map);
      markerGroup.addLayer(radius);
    }
    this.map.addLayer(markerGroup);
  }

  locate(lat,lng){
    this.map.locate({
      setView: true,
      maxZoom: 10,
      timeout: 10000,
      enableHighAccuracy: true
    }).on('locationfound', (e) => {
      var LeafIcon = leaflet.Icon.extend({
        options: {
            shadowUrl: 'https://example.com/assets/themes/frontend/auth/images/markers/marker-shadow.png',
            iconSize: [25, 38], // size of the icon
            iconAnchor: [12, 38], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            popupAnchor: [115, 110] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor  
        }
    });

    let redIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'https://example.com/assets/themes/frontend/auth/images/markers/marker-icon-red.png'})

    if(lat != null && lng != null){
      this.lat = lat;
      this.lng = lng;
    } else {
      this.lat = e.latitude;
      this.lng = e.longitude;
    }

    this.markerGroupSelf = leaflet.featureGroup();
    let markerSelf = leaflet.marker([this.lat, this.lng], {icon: redIcon});
    let radiusSelf = leaflet.circle([this.lat, this.lng], 5000,{color: 'red', opacity:.5});

    this.markerGroupSelf.addLayer(radiusSelf);
    this.markerGroupSelf.addLayer(markerSelf);
    this.map.addLayer(this.markerGroupSelf);

    }).on('locationerror', (err) => {
      this.presentAlert();
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to show all the `code` which is related to this issue.

Comment: Added full code.

Comment: You need to show the places where you call this `presentAlert()`? Is that only here `}).on('locationerror', (err) => {
      this.presentAlert();
    })`

Comment: Yes, thats the only place. I run the locate function with GPS disabled then the alert appears, but after closing it and running the locate function again when it hits the error part i get the same alert 2 times. The 'locationerror' is fired 2 times.

Comment: Can you share the `API url` where you use?